# Emiting array from content script to main addon script

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on

I delete elements stored in simple-storage array in main script.This creates null elements in the simple-storage array.So i run a script to return a new array to the main addon script (which contains no null elements) and i assign it to simple-storage array.But the main script gets only one element not the entire array. How to get the entire array?
below is the main addon code part:

```
text_entry.port.on("del", function (todel) {
  console.log(todel);
  site_l=ss.storage.sites.length;

  for(var i=0;i<site_l;i++)
  {
    if(ss.storage.sites[i]==todel)
    {
        delete ss.storage.sites[i];
    }   
  }
  text_entry.port.emit("c",ss.storage.sites);
  text_entry.port.on("cd",function(arr){
    ss.storage.sites=[];
    ss.storage.sites=arr;
  });

});
```

script which returns new array containing no null elements:

```
self.port.on("c",function(arr)
{
    var a=arr;
    var l=a.length;

    function isEmpty(element) {
    if(element!=null)
      return true;
    }

    a=a.filter(isEmpty);
    self.port.emit("cd",a);
});
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing here - is text_entry a page-mod instance, or what? Can you provide a reduced example that people could run and test for themselves?

Comment: if you have a non-sdk version i can help you out. can you make a simple test case, i can make a demo addon for you.

Comment: @canuckistani its panel instance. User selects items from a list in panel and clicks delete button which makes the panel content script to get and store the selected items from the list in a local array.And now it needs to send that array to the main script.I found a way. Convert the array to string and pass it to main script and use split to make it an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
for(var i=0;i<site_l;i++) {
  if(ss.storage.sites[i]==todel) {
    delete ss.storage.sites[i];
  }   
}
```

With `ss.storage.sites.splice(ss.storage.sites.indexOf(todel), 1)`